# Avoid iframe url affecting browser's back button

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a web page where I have two iframes. I set the url (location) of the iframes in the page onload event. This is done to "delay load" the content. That is, the main page content is rendered first, then the iframe content with e.g. Like buttons, trust logos etc. are displayed. This speeds up the page rendering considerably.

However...

Clicking the back button first removes the trust logo. Then another back button click removes the Like buttons. The third click finally takes the user to the previous page.

Is there any way to avoid the URLs of the iframes to go into the browser history, while maintaining the above functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: Not the iframe problem, but the Back program.I removed the iframe. It was for a "Norton Secured" logo, which by default is a script in an iframe. I now show a logo image instead, that goes to the verification URL if clicked. Not "by the Norton book", but it solved the Back problem.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using iFrames, if you really want to `improve rendering` like this, use AJAX. However there are numerous other problems if your page actually renders slow, how large is it, and how is it structured?

Comment: That's not the point. The page is now super fast, because the big javascript libraries are loaded after the main page content is rendered.

Comment: In that case, cant you load the javascript library when the page is loaded?